# Connect openfire to smack

Tags: java, android

I'm using the ***Smack API*** for an i'm android app and don't want to use the public services, so i downloaded ***Openfire*** but have no idea how to connect them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is:

– Download the library files for Smack API and integrate in your project.

– Connect to the server.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder;
    configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
    try {
        configBuilder.setXmppDomain(OpenFireApiInteractor.XMPP_DOMAIN);

        configBuilder.setHost(ipAddress);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        connection.addConnectionListener(this);

    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[Here is an example that you can use](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/).